# How to validate POST xhr

Tags: typescript, cypress

[image: )]

How can I validate if this xhr post is aborted (in this case it should be positive scenario and test should pass?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just solved it.

```js
describe('Register', function() {
  it('Step 0', function() {
    cy.visit('localhost:4200')
  })
  it('Email validation', function() {
    cy.server();
    cy.route('POST', '**sign_in').as('signin');

    cy.get('[data-cy="signup-input"]').type('test@test.pl')
    cy.get('[data-cy=input-password]').type('test123456{enter}')
    cy.get('[data-cy="email-error1"]').should('be.visible')

    cy.wait('@signin').its('status').should('equal', 401)


  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done with chai expect assertions like so:

```
cy.wait('@signin').then((xhr) => {
    expect(xhr.status).to.equal(401);
});
```

You can read more about it [in cypress documentation for cy.wait()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Nesting). They also have tonnes of examples in their [XHR Assertions examples github project](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/server-communication__xhr-assertions).

Answer (score 0):

this is the new way to solve it:

```
  cy.intercept(
    {
    method:'GET',
    url:'/api/channels/e5932cce
    }).as('loginLoaded')
 
  cy.get("@loginLoaded").then((xhr) => {
    cy.wait('@loginLoaded').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 401)
    })
```